# Custom scrollbar jScrollPane appears twice in iframe

Tags: javascript, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have a problem with a custom scrollbar appearing twice in an iframe.
The scrollbar looks OK in IE, but not in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Here you can have a look to the page:
http://tenforty.ch/index.php/setlist

I have the following code in my iframe:

```
<style>
iframe {
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>


<iframe scrolling="no" width="690" height="680" frameborder="0"
src="templates/musicband/setlist.html"></iframe>
```

Here is the code in my html file:

```
<style type="text/css" id="page-css">
/* Styles specific to this particular page */
.scroll-pane
{
width: 690px;
height: 680px;
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

I tried out with different widths and hights, tried also 100%. But it looks even worse when changing this.

Here you can see a printscreen how it sould look like (taken in Internet Explorer):
http://www.tenforty.ch/scrollbar.jpg

Can you help me out?

Thanks!
Swiz

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get two scrollbars is because the page you link to in the iframe (http://tenforty.ch/templates/musicband/setlist.html) is *also* creating a scrollbar:

```
$(function() {
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```